# how do I re-write/redirect URLs in Gunicorn web server configuration?

Tags: python, https, gunicorn, url-pattern

I'm building a Django-based app, and I need it to use secure requests. The secure requests in my site are enabled and manually writing the url gets it through fine.

As I have quite a lot of urls I don't want to do it manually, but instead do something so Django always sends secure requests.

How can I make it so it always send `https`?

Comment: If you want to have all URLs served over HTTPS then you can simply configure your web server to redirect any requests to the wrong protocol.  Django's URL configuration is relative, so if you start on an HTTPS connection you will remain on one. (Think about running apps at multiple domains for testing.  And local development.  You don't want to force HTTPS on every request into Django).

Comment: Ok, perfect. So.... How can I do it??

Comment: What web server are you using?  Apache?  Gunicorn + Nginx? This is not a Django question, but rather a "how do I re-write/redirect URLs in X web server configuration?"

Comment: Gunicorn + Nginx  Thanks for the info on the question name

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-nginx-redirect-all-http-to-https/